# Reduce the size of soft keyboard in android

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

[image: Display Picture]

Usually the soft keyboard fits to the screen size in both portrait and land scape mode. I am developing an app, in that i have an edit text. On edit text click "Is it possible to reduce the size of soft keyboard on land scape mode?". Please guide me through this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft See this. `adjustPan` may help your issue.

Comment: @SatanPandeya how to do this in a fragment? On click of edit text, keyboard pop's up. I want the size of the keyboard to be half of the screen(land scape mode).